# Spring Dynamic (Expandable) List form

Tags: java, jquery, spring, dynamic-forms

I am having problems with dynamic forms in spring. In our form we want to specify a title, 
and add a number of questions. We have an "add" button to add question input form using
jquery.

Our form has one question field when it is requested. Extra fields are added every time
the "add" button is pressed. When submitting it seems that the extra fields are not being
submitted (the first one is received by the controller). Why are the extra fields not <strike>received</strike> being sent?

I roughly based my code on [this dynamic binding list example](http://eggsylife.co.uk/2009/11/30/spring-forms-dynamic-lists-and-ajax/).

My model consists of a class "Report" which has a
"title" and a list of "Researchquestion"s.
A short version of the two model classes is below. Roo takes care of all the getters and
setters

```
@Entity
@RooJavaBean
@RooEntity
public class Report{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="report")
    private List<Researchquestion> researchquestions;
}



@Entity
@RooJavaBean
@RooEntity
public class Researchquestion {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;    
    @NotEmpty
    private String question;
}
```

Here the jspx for the form

```
<div xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
    version="2.0">
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <spring:url value="/admin/report/appendquestion" var="insert_url"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var questionPosition = 0;
        $("#addQuestionButton").click(function() {
            questionPosition++;

            $.get("${insert_url}", { fieldId: questionPosition},
                function(data){
                    $("#insertAbove").before($(data));
            });
        });
    });
    </script>

    <div class="list_overview_box span-19">
        <spring:url value="/admin/report/" var="form_url"/>
        <div class="list_overview_content">
            <table>
                <form:form action="${form_url}" method="post" modelAttribute="report">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="span-3">Veld</th>
                        <th>Waarde</th>
                        <th class="span-5">Errors</th>
                    </tr>

        <!-- Title -->
                    <tr class="row">
                        <td class="vmiddle aleft">Title</td>
                        <td><form:input path="title" /></td>
                        <td></td>                           
                    </tr>

           <!-- the "add" button -->
                    <tr class="row">
                        <td class="vmiddle aleft">Researchquestions</td>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="button" id="addQuestionButton" value="Add question" /></td>
                    </tr>
           <!-- First Researchquestion -->
                    <spring:bind path="researchquestions[0].question">
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="vmiddle aleft">Question 1</td>
                            <td><form:input path="${status.expression}" /></td>
                            <td></td>                           
                        </tr>
                    </spring:bind>

        <!--  Save button, extra question's are added here -->
                    <tr id="insertAbove" class="row">
                        <spring:message code="button.save" var="form_submit"/>
                        <td colspan="3"><input id="proceed" type="submit" value="${form_submit}" /></td>
                    </tr>   
                </form:form> 
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the page the controller returns after the jquery .get request
I have the idea that I need to use `<spring:bind>` just like in the form above.
When I do this however I get an error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
>   target object for bean name 'researchquestions[1]' available as request
>   attribute

appendquestion.jspx

```
<jsp:root version="2.0"
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:tiles="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"
    xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
    xmlns:roo="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags" >

    <tr class="row">
        <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />   

        <td class="vmiddle aleft">Question ${questionNumber +1}</td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="report.researchquestions[${questionNumber}].question" size="40" />
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

</jsp:root>
```

Here the relevant @ModelAttribute and @requestmapping methods in our controller
The @ModelAttribute method makes sure that the List in an instance of
AutoPopulatingList, I am not really sure if this is required though.
If I add `@RequestParam Map formdata` to the `create()` (POST) method then the formdata does
contain `researchquestions[0].question` but not `researchquestions\[1\].question` or any other question fields
that have been added after pressing the "add" button

```
@ModelAttribute("report")
public Report getReport(Long id) {
    Report result;
    if(id != null){
        result = Report.findReport(id);
    } else{
        result = new Report();
    }

    //Make sure the List in result is an AutoPopulatingList
    List<Researchquestion> vragen = result.getResearchquestions();
    if(vragen == null){
        result.setResearchquestions(new AutoPopulatingList<Researchquestion>(Researchquestion.class));
    } else if(!(vragen instanceof AutoPopulatingList)){
        result.setResearchquestions(new AutoPopulatingList<Researchquestion>(
                vragen, Researchquestion.class));
    }

    return result;
}

/**
 * Aanmaken Report
 * @param report
 * @param result
 * @param modelMap
 * @return
 */
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(@Valid @ModelAttribute("report") Report report,
        BindingResult result, ModelMap modelMap) {

    if (report == null) throw new InvalidBeanException("A report is required");

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        modelMap.addAttribute("report", report);
        return "admin/report/create";
    }

    report.persist();

    //create questions
    for(Researchquestion question : report.getResearchquestions()){
        question.setProfielwerkstuk(report);
        question.persist();
    }

    report.merge();
    return "redirect:/admin/report";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/appendquestion", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String appendResearchquestionField(@RequestParam Integer fieldId, ModelMap modelMap){
    modelMap.addAttribute("questionNumber", fieldId);
    return "admin/report/appendquestion";
}
```

**Additional info** (as requested by Ralph)

Below the HTML that Spring generates, researchquestions[0].question is in the form by default, researchquestions[1].question is added after pressing the "add" button

```
 <tr class="row">
    <td class="vmiddle aleft">Question 1</td>
    <td>
        <input id="researchquestions0.question" type="text" value=""
             name="researchquestions[0].question">
    </td>

    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr class="row">
    <td class="vmiddle aleft">Question 2</td>
    <td>
        <input id="researchquestions1.question" type="text" size="40" value="" name="researchquestions[1].question">
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Below the relevant info from Live HTTP Headers
I intered "This is the title" in the "title" field, "This is the first question" in the "Question 1" field, and "This is the second question" in the "Question 2" field (which has been added by pressing the "add" button.

It is clear that researchquestions[0].question is being submitted, but researchquestions[1].question is not submitted at all in the POST request.

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 73
   title=This+is+the+title&researchquestions%5B0%5D.question=This+is+the+first+question
```

**My suspicions**
The difference between the first question (that is in the form by default) and the subsequent questions is that the first question uses `<spring:bind>` and the subsequent ones do not. When I remove the `<spring:bind>` tag for the first question, the researchquestions[0] is also not submitted.

As I explained above, I get an IllegalStateException when adding the `<spring:bind>` to the appendquestion.jspx. It seems that spring searches for the object `researchquestions[1]`
instead of `report.researchquestions[1]`

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
>   target object for bean name 'researchquestions[1]' available as request
>   attribute

Comment: Fritsie: Please use any html tool (for example Firebug/Network, Firefox Http Live Headers,...) to check if the parameter onderzoeksvragen[0] and onderzoeksvragen[1] ... are submitted. And add the results of your obervation to your question. -- So one can decided if the problem is on the client or server side. -- And please add a snippet of the html output for 2 items.

Comment: I added the info you requested, the second researchquestion "researchquestion[1]" is not being submitted.  
    

I translated the Dutch terms to English, for example "onderzoeksvragen" is now "researchquestion"

Comment: Why are you requesting the additional HTML to add to the form when a user presses the "add" button rather than just constructing the HTML elements client-side (in the JavaScript)? You get the IllegalStateException when trying to call `<spring:bind>` when retreiving the content via AJAX because there is no command/form object to bind the expression to - since this is a totally separate request.

Comment: If this is really the HTML and the Http Post was for a for where the both input fields have had values, than I do not understand the cause. -- Did you extend the fields with some dojo widgets? (then I would try to remove them) -- If this does not help, then I would add the second field to the initial form (the ajax relaod), test if this works, and (if it works) search for the difference in HTML betreen the working and not working version.

Comment: @Fritsie: matt b is right with the cause for the bind error - In a first step you can replace the `<form:input` with an norml html `<input name="researchquestions[1].question" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason why the form was not being submitted correctly. I noticed the following HTML in firebug:

```
<form id="researchquestion" method="post" action="/site/admin/researchquestion/"></form>
```

The form tag is closed immediately, so the HTML generated by spring was not correct.
It appears that this was because the form was inside the table switching the `<table>` and `<form:form>` tags fixed the issue.

#### Original code

```
<table>
    <form:form action="${form_url}" method="post" modelAttribute="report">
         <!--  Code here -->  
    </form:form> 
</table>
```

#### Working version

```
<form:form action="${form_url}" method="post" modelAttribute="report">
    <table>
         <!--  Code here -->  
    </table>
</form:form>
```

In a `<table>` it is only allowed to use table related tags such as `<tr>` `<th>` and `<td>`. Which is probably why Spring immediately closed the `<form>` tag.

Comment: my hero! Your solution probably saved me a day or 2, kudos for you my friend!!