# What is <spring:bind> for? When to use it, and when not to use it?

Tags: java, forms, spring

I am having problems with submitting form data in spring. `<spring:bind>` seems to be a part of the solution. See my full problem  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845450/spring-dynamic-expandable-list-form).

The documentation of BindTag [found here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/BindTag.html) is not clear to me. Why is `<spring:bind>` needed in some cases to submit data, while it is not needed in most cases?

What are the typical cases where the `<spring:bind>` must be used in order for a form to function properly?

Answer (score 7):

You will find the tag `<spring:bind>` useful when you want to parse multiple objects from an input form. Here's a modified example from the Spring's doc (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.6/taglib/tag/BindTag.html):

```
<form method="post">
        ## now bind on the name of the company
        <spring:bind path="company.name">
        ## render a form field, containing the value and the expression
        Name: <input 
            type="text" 
            value="<c:out value="${status.value}"/>"
            name="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>">
        </spring:bind>

<spring:bind path="address.street">
    Name: <input 
        type="text"
        value="<c:out value="${status.value}"/>"
        name="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>">
</spring:bind>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I've never used this tag myself, my understanding of the documentation is this. A  tag will provide you with information about the binding status of a form property to a bean. For example in:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="employee">
    <form:input path="name"/>
    <spring:bind path="name"/>
    <spring:bind path="employee"/>
</form:form>
```

The tag will display (or expose through a BindStatus object) all errors that have occurred with the name attribute (the first case) and all errors on the Employee entity and its attributes (the second case). I am not sure that this tag has anything to do with the succesfulness of submitting data, but rather that it's used as an information tool.